# Should "at least" be used to start a sentence or finish it?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Which should it be? Both sound fine to me.

> At least how many years of experience the successful candidate should have?
>
> How many years of experience the successful candidate should have at least?

Comment: What is the minimum number of years of experience the successful candidate should have?

Comment: As indicated by @HotLicks, neither of your suggestions seem appropriate. Perhaps choose a better sample to use to frame your question?

Comment: Neither of them is fine.  They are questions, they need inversion at a minimum.

Comment: Hi & welcome to EL&U. One of the expectations of Stack Exchange is that you demonstrate your initial attempts at research yourself; for example, did you look the words up in a dictionary or other reference source? Please take the site tour and review the Help Centre for additional guidance. Our sister site for English Language Learners may also be of interest, if you are learning English.

Comment: The most natural is *At least how many years of experience should the successful candidate have?* (It wouldn't be wrong to move it to the end, so long as the specific construction is kept, but it would be a little odd.)

Answer (score -1):

As was mentioned in the comments, your examples contain a grammar mistake. Putting it at the end should be correct:

*How many years of experience should the candidate have at least?*

Putting "At least" in front would be incorrect.

Note that there is a construct where "at least" goes to the front of a sentence, but then the phrase has the meaning of "in any case" whereas you want to say "at the minimum":

*At least that is my opinion.*

*At least you have a choice.*

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/at%20least